# 3 Patterns in one for x in range(y) loop without list comprehension

Tags: python, loops, range

Instead of using 3 loops separately, I'd like to use only one loop and speed up the code.

There are 3 different patterns of `range(0,150)`, increasing 3 per loop:

```
0,3,6,9...
1,4,7,10...
2,5,8,11....
```

My code:

```
fromlist = [1,2,3,4,5]
req1list = ['z','t','y']
req2list = [21,39,52]
req3list = [100,200,300]

for i in range(0,150,3):
    req1list.append(fromlist[i])
for j in range(1,150,3):
    req2list.append(fromlist[j])
for x in range(2,151,3):
    req3list.append(fromlist[x])
```

Note that lists are already created and there is data inside the file. Thus, I thought that list comprehension would be impossible.

Another note: please ignore the list lengths, in my file the lists are far longer and don't cause errors in `[]`.

Is there any way that unites these 3 loops in one, and speed up the code?

Comment: Your ranges will lead to errors.

Comment: forgot to explain this. please ignore that, I edited the question

Comment: Just to note, you can write `fromlist = [1,2,3,4,5,...]` to informally suggest a "long enough" list. (Yes, it's valid Python syntax and actually means something different, but it's understood what you mean for a SO question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to perform three appends in each iteration (in one loop), you'll get faster results if you call `extend` instead of `append`. You could also use slicing to avoid comprehension:

```
req1list.extend(fromlist[::3])
req2list.extend(fromlist[1::3])
req3list.extend(fromlist[2::3])
```

And if it is important to stop at 150, add it in the slice operation:

```
req1list.extend(fromlist[:150:3])
# ...etc
```

Comment: You can use `None` in place of `len(fromlist)`. Since `fromlist` is, in fact, a `list` and not an arbitrary iterator, you can also simply write `req1list.extend(fromlist[0::3])`, `req2list.extend(fromlist[1::3])`, etc.

Comment: Of course, thanks chepner. I dropped the `islice` part.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach would be to use the `grouper` function defined in the `itertools` documentation.

```
def grouper(iterable, n, *, incomplete='fill', fillvalue=None):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    if incomplete == 'fill':
        return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
    if incomplete == 'strict':
        return zip(*args, strict=True)
    if incomplete == 'ignore':
        return zip(*args)
    else:
        raise ValueError('Expected fill, strict, or ignore')
```

With this, you can write

```
for x, y, z in grouper(fromlist, 3):
    req1list.append(x)
    req2list.append(y)
    req3list.append(z)
```

(You can copy the definition of `grouper` from the documentation to your own code, or use the third-party `more-itertools` package which includes it and many more useful functions for dealing with iterators.)